# How to change the ordering of two divs when on mobile?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to change the order of two divs in a container when they get to mobile size.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Is this possible to change it so that it will change to

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="div1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What sort of browser support do you need for the solution? Basically, what version of IE and up?

Comment: only the compliant browsers (ie. firefox, chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pure css to do that

```
.container{
    display:table;
}
.div1{
    display:table-footer-group;
}
.div2{
    display:table-header-group;
}
```

make sure you put it in a @media query.

Comment: Have you prepared that answer in advance? Seems like a sock-puppet account…

Comment: Nope. I just happened to be working on a project with that same problem. So I had the code there already.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on [which browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) you need to support, you can use flexbox to switch the order of the divs.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.div1 {
  order: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 780px)  {
  .div1 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hexe3dz/)

Comment: Yeah, thought of this, it will be a nice elegant solution down the track but I need to support IE10/11 atm, might work for OP though

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using flexbox by reversing the order.

```
.container {
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
  flex-direction: column;
}
@media(min-width:768px){
  .container {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/oxJNqz

Answer (score -1):

You can use two separate classes and make only one visible at a time depending on the media width.

First create you CSS

```
//This container is only visible on devices with 1025px or more such as iPad in landscape or portrait view
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px)  {
    .desktop-container {
    Display:none;
    }
 }


// This container is only visible on smaller devices with screen size 360px - 1024px
@media screen and (min-width:360px) and (max-width:1024px) {
    .mobile-container {
     Display:none;
    }
 }
```

Now create your markup...

```
<div class="desktop-container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>

<div class="mobile-container">
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to have two divs just to change the order. Thanks anyway